# Reading and organizing data from a website in java approach

Tags: java, html, url, multidimensional-array

My project is to build a schedule maker for my university where students can select courses and it will suggest possible schedules for them.

First Step IMO is to get the data from the university timetable from [here](https://dalonline.dal.ca/PROD/fysktime.P_DisplaySchedule?s_term=201310&s_subj=MGMT&format=1)
and then putting the important items (the course identifier number called CRN, the title, section, time, room etc) in some form of multidimensional array which I can then use to process the data and build the schedule.

My question is this:

Is using [the method described in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingURL.html) to get the data and then dump it into an array like {ID, CRN, TITLE, TIME-DAYS, TIME-HOURS, ROOM} a good way to proceed or am I making things unnecessarily complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably need a library for parsing the HTML. I would suggest jsoup: http://jsoup.org/

They have a cookbook to get you started:
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/

A simple example from their website which reads data from wikipedia:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");
```